# Error (use-package): Cannot load magit

Tags: magit, use-package

I am not sure if that is a problem on my site or more people are experiencing this. I thought at first that I broke something in my config file, but after loading by backup `.emacs.d`, the error is the same.

I put `use-package` ensuring magit up to my .init.el so it looks like so:

```el
;;; PACKAGES CONFIGURATION
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
             ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
             ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
             ("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
             ("elpy" . "https://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/")))
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

'(use-package-compute-statistics)

;; Ensure system binaries keyword
(use-package use-package-ensure-system-package
  :ensure t)

(use-package auto-package-update
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t)
  (setq auto-package-update-hide-results t)
  (auto-package-update-maybe))

(use-package magit
    :ensure t
    :pin melpa)

;; Evaluation of packages and all personal configuration is exported
;; to  `~/.emacs.d/myinit.org`.
(org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/config.org"))

(provide 'init.el)
;;; init.el ends here
```

I get also this list of unable to activate packages at startup in `*Messages*` buffer:

```
Unable to activate package ‘ghub’.
Required package ‘graphql-0.1’ is unavailable
Unable to activate package ‘magit’.
Required package ‘ghub-2.0.1’ is unavailable
Unable to activate package ‘ghub’.
Required package ‘graphql-0.1’ is unavailable
Unable to activate package ‘ghub’.
Required package ‘graphql-0.1’ is unavailable
Unable to activate package ‘ghub+’.
Required package ‘ghub-2.0’ is unavailable
```

If nobody finds an answer here, I will rise an issue as it can be matter of a bug.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The one I write in the title, exactly: `Error (use-package): Cannot load magit`

Comment: Maybe `M-x package-refresh-contents` and try again, since package.el is complaining graphql is not available.

Comment: I forget to mention I  been already trying this and reinstalling `magit` as well.

Comment: Looks like [magit/ghub#69](https://github.com/magit/ghub/issues/69), though that is supposed to be fixed by now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue appeared when I updated `ghub`'s Melpa recipe to depend on `graphql` without realizing that the latter was not yet available from Melpa.

You might be able to resolve this simply by using `M-x package-refresh-contents` and then trying again.

Or not. It is also possible that `package.el` got itself into a bad state and cannot find its way out of it on its own anymore. If that is so, then install `graphql` explicitly. If that does not work, then also try reinstalling `ghub`.